# IOS Swift TextView UITapGestureRecognizer with tab to move cursor

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

i used default keyboard and custom keyboard

if textview touch event when custom keyboard is showing, change to default keyboard

```
class ReplyPage: UIViewController ,UITextViewDelegate,EmojiKeyboardDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
     @IBOutlet weak var replyArea: UITextView!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()          
            replyArea.delegate=self
            emojiView.delegate = self
            replyPage = self
            let tapTerm = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textViewTouch))
            tapTerm.delegate = self
            replyArea.addGestureRecognizer(tapTerm)

            more code...
      }


     @objc func textViewTouch(){
        if isEmoji{
            replyArea.inputView = nil
            replyArea.reloadInputViews()
            isEmoji = false
            emojiButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"emoji"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }else{
            replyArea.reloadInputViews()
            replyArea.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

this code is worked

but can't move cursor in `textview`

default tab is move cursor

but `UITapGesture` override this so can't work

how to use Both default tab and `UITapGesture`

Can i Listen `Textview` Touch without `UITapGesture`?

can't `textViewDidBeginEditing()`

TextView Tap do not call `textViewDidBeginEditing` after first open custom keyboard.

because First Custom Keyboard Open already call `textViewDidBeginEditing`

Answer (score 0):

Please add protocol TextViewDelegate in your viewController .
And add 
self.replyArea.delegate = self

Comment: add More code in Post and
same work after replyArea.delegate = self